# Navigation drawer change color

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am using Navigation drawer using [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) example. I want just change blue color to orange color how could I do this? I mean change listview selector color, actionbar selctor color everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do 2 things for this.

1. for listview create your customize listview selector (see answer @raghunandan )
2. for actionbar Go [here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=MyOrange&compat=holo&theme=dark&actionbarstyle=transparent&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=2D2D2D,100&secondaryColor=151515,100&tabColor=ff7900,100&tertiaryColor=3F3F3F,100&accentColor=ff7900,100&cabBackColor=002E3E,100&cabHighlightColor=ff7900,100) create your style and set your style from manifest, set your application theme your created style

Comment: That's great site. Never heard of this. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use a selector

in drawable folder have selector.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/press" />
    <item  android:state_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

In drawable folder press.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#FF9D21"/>     
</shape>
```

In drawable foldernormal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#8BC7EB"/>    
</shape>
```

In the drawer_list_item.xml

```
android:background="@drawable/selector"
```

For styling the bar

```
  <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
         <item name="android:background">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/press</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

In your manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:theme="@style/MyActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You can specify the theme for a particular activity instead of entire application.

More information

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: it's about only customize listView or actionbar too?

Comment: @bauer9664 its only for the drawer list items.

Comment: @bauer9664 use styles to change the bar color https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: @bauer9664 check the snap shot. the bar color is changed to orange. The snap does not look good taken from emulator

Comment: You should also include `android:layout_height=""` and `android:layout_width=""` attributes to selector or Android Studio/Gradle won't compile your app

Answer (score 0):

You need to use selectors.

Check this tutorial for more. [customizing listviews](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/customizing-list-views-in-your-android-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

For ActionBar backgroownd:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute to the answer given by @Raghunandan. In the list you can distinguish between items clicked (android:state_pressed) from items activated (android:state_activated), so if you click on the item in the list that is activated, the click is visualized.

Create an activated.xml under the drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#6A6A6A"/>
</shape>
```

And modify the selector.xml adding the state_activated modifier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/press" />

    <item android:state_activated="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/activated" />

    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Selector to achieve this. You can use either `@drawable` or `@color`.

```
item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>

item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>

item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_selected" android:state_activated="true"/
```