# Actionbar action icons not showing up

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I have searched many questions but unable to solve my problem. Please help me in this. i have used `app:showAsAction="always"` but even them i am unable to get icon on actionbar. i have also tried `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` but didnt work. I am a beeginner in android and help will be really greatfull. Thanks in advance
my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mavilla.laundrynotes" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Apptheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Apptheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Apptheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Apptheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/Crimson</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

my menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="Add"
        android:icon="@mipmap/add"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

main_activity.java

```
package mavilla.laundrynotes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change extends `Activity` to `ActionBarActivity`. Also you need to be using styles derived from `Theme.AppCompat` if you are using appcompat

Comment: If not using appcompat then you should use `android` prefix and not `app`

Comment: Thanks a ton. its working. but the actionbar color is Dark but i want it to be crimson as in code above

Comment: you will get the color you want once you override the background of the styles

Comment: I am really sorry but i didnt understand that. could you please explain

Comment: your code should work fine as you have set the color in styles.xml. I don't understand what is wrong in that. You can check my answer here answered long time before the release of lollipop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759798/navigation-drawer-change-color

Comment: i tried your answer but still its dark color

Comment: whats your exact problem ,  your actin bar icons do not appear or you cant change the action bar color ?

Comment: first my problem was regarding actionbar icons but solved with the sollution given by @Raghunandan but now my actionbar color is dark instead of Crimson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code and make your own customizations :

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/activated_background</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/ActionBarWidget</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@color/teal</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/teal</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NavDrawerActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/teal</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/menu</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/back</item>

    </style>

    <style name="NavDrawerActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/teal</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/back</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/teal</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
        <item name="android:height">@dimen/action_bar_height</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarWidget" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>

</resources>
```