# Change Color of Navigation drawer icon and Overflow menu icon in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I have followed many answers in stack overflow but still unable to find solution of my problem.
I have followed below link to change color of navigation drawer:
[Navigation drawer change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759798/navigation-drawer-change-color)

I have followed below method to change color of overflow menu:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/MyToolbarTheme.Base"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        />
```

In Styles.XML

```
<style name="MyToolbarThemeSimple.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/overflow_simple</item>
    </style>
    <style name="overflow_simple" parent="MyToolbarThemeSimple.Base">
        <item name="android:color">@color/windowBackground</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/windowBackground</item>
    </style>
```

I want to change color of below navigation drawer and overflow menu to white
[image]

Comment: Instead of parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

Comment: Its not working .....

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following to your `MyToolbarThemeSimple.Base` in order to adapt the color of the overflow menu dots:

```
<style name="MyToolbarThemeSimple.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/MyToolbarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
    <!-- Used to for the title of the toolbar -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- Used to color back button and overflow menu dots -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

For the `ActionbarDrawerToggle` you need to add the `drawerArrowStyle` item to your AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Other items -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggleStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggleStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```